# Python Sphinx documenting through directories

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm having to use Sphinx to document a whole project folder, with lots of subfolders and python scripts inside them.

What's the best solution to automate this process? The project will be constantly updated, and the documentation should be properly updated.

- Use python to make a routine to create lots of `.rst` files plus `automodule` Sphinx directive to capture docstrings;
- Use some Sphinx directives inside `index.rst` in order to fetch folders and find all the scripts automatically (**Is there something like this?**)

Sphinx documentation is so though to understand, and I didn't find something like that I want.

Could you help me to discover where to search for the solution?

Thank you!

Comment: create a script to do that and put it in a cron job

Comment: You can use sphinx-apidoc: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html

Comment: Or maybe this extension: https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-autopackagesummary/

Comment: Thanks, mzjn! I have found apidoc after writing this post, but I'm still learning how to use it, because some other problens are happening. I will create a post for this if the problem persists

Comment: And I didn't know autopackagesummary, which sounds good too. If my solution with apidoc (which doesn't have the greatest documentation...), I will try autopackagesummary. Thanks!